# Tortoise equivalent 'replace with latest from repository"?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, revert

I have a PC for Windows development and Linux box for Android development.  Our source control is Subversion and I use TortoiseSVN on Windows and Subclipse plug-in in Eclipse on Linux.

Sometimes I'll edit a file for some experiment but I don't want to keep the changes.  In Subclipse all I have to to is *"Replace with latest from Repository"* to bring it back in line with the latest committed code.

What's the equivalent of this in TortoiseSVN? Is there a simple one-step way to replace my local file with the current latest in the repository?

**N.B.** I don't want to do an *"Update"* because according to the documentation that will merge in others' changes.  I want a complete replacement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-step action for that.

Right-click on working copy folder `TortoiseSVN -> Revert` & choose the files which should have their local changes undone, and then do a  `TortoiseSVN -> Update`.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `svn revert` or the same command of TortoiseSVN context menu: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revert.html and then `svn update` the working copy,
- Ultimate solution: `svn checkout` a fresh working copy or do it though TortoiseSVN context menu.

Comment: Only doing a revert will not update the working copy with the latest changes from the repository.

Comment: Thanks @marapet! I thought this step after reverting was, hm, obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try Right Click the item > Tortoise SVN > Update to revision... > select Head Revision and you are done!!!

Comment: This will not get rid of local changes.

Comment: I said I didn't want to do an Update because that will just merge in the head; it won't replace my local changes.